# Jquery mobile- How to open android settings page on button click

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have designed a `Phonegap` app using `jQuery Mobile`. I need to know how to open the settings page of android devices on a button click...

Your help will be highly appreciated.....

Messages wil open an HTML page but i need Settings to open the android device settings page

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu" data-theme="d">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:30px;" data-theme="d">
        <li><a href="messages.html">Messages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Check the code in the description

Comment: i think you want to use use webintent plugin to open this setting activity in android

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Thanks

Comment: how to use it on jquery mobile?

Comment: @HridoyDutta : You can create a custom plugin for button click and in that plugin you can add this code.

Answer (score -1):

You can't open Android Settings from JavaScript. You need to install PhoneGap plugin into your app and consume Android Native API (Java) .

In order to consume Android Native API to open Android Setting Page, you need to create and install PhoneGap plugin into your project.

You can not directly open Android Setting Page with just only JavaScript API. PhoneGap Plugin enables you to consume Android Native API via JavaScript.

Creating Android Native plugin requires you to know about Java.
For more details, please look [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) 
.

In your Java plugin, call the code below:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```